# How to find if a list contains any element of another list in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I have a `sqlite` table where there is a column `selected_dates`. This column contains a list of `CustomDates` object. I want to query if this column contains any item of other list of same type( `customDates`). But I can't find any way. I've tried:

```java
    @Query("SELECT * FROM schedule_table WHERE (type_daily IS 1) OR (:monthOfYear IS 1) " +
            "OR (selectedDates IN (:customDates))" +
            "ORDER BY scheduleID DESC")
    LiveData<List<Schedule>> getSchedulesOfThisWeek(String monthOfYear, List<ScheduleType.Dates> customDates);
```

Here is my sample data (`List<Date>` object is stored in `json` format) [Image of data in `sqlite browser`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTfBW.png):

```json
[{"dayOfMonth":1,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":2,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":3,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":4,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":5,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":6,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":7,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":8,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":9,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":10,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":11,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":12,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":13,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":14,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":15,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":16,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":17,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":18,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":19,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":20,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":21,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":22,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":23,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":24,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":25,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":26,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":27,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":28,"month":8},{"dayOfMonth":29,"month":8}]
```

**In a word, How to find if two List Intersects each other or not in sqlite?**

Comment: Note, that you should use `=` sign when comparing numbers.  `IS` operator is used to check for `NULL`.  Also can you show some sample data?  Table structure with data would be very useful.

Comment: @AleksG sir I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Room Database Stores data in primary data types. So your selected dates are in `TEXT` format. You can perform `LIKE` operation to find the matching columns.

Room also provides a annotation `@RawQuery`. You can use this. For your problem this might be a solution:

in `Dao` interface:

```java
@RawQuery(observedEntities = Schedule.class)
LiveData<List<Schedule>> getSchedule(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
```

And to use `getSchedule()`:

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM schedule_table WHERE " +
                "(type_daily IS 1) OR (" + monthOfYear + " IS 1) OR " +
                conditions + " ORDER BY scheduleID DESC";
        return mDao.getSchedule(new SimpleSQLiteQuery(query));
```

where `condition` is the `String` of the dates you want to find. For example:

```java
String condition = "selectedDates LIKE '%{\"dayOfMonth\":1,\"month\":8}%' OR selectedDates LIKE '%{\"dayOfMonth\":5,\"month\":8}%';
```

You can create a method which will generate this string based on a `List<ScheduleType.Dates>`.